# php cookie with domain parameter

Tags: php, apache

I am unable to set a cookie in one domain and read it in another. I have tried a million different examples but i have had no luck at all.

can someone please point out what is going wrong?

domainone.com

```
setcookie('testcookie','cookie example',time()+30*24*60*60,'/','domaintwo.com',false,true)
```

domaintwo.com

```
echo $_COOKIE[testcookie];

var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php cookie cross 2 top level domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013204/php-cookie-cross-2-top-level-domains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. Search for [Cross Domain Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+cross+domain+cookies) related questions on SO to see workarounds (though none is trivial).