# Apache mod-rewrite redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to do:

if user go to **test.com** then server must redirect to **main.com/check.php**, checks something and return back to **test.com**

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^main\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://main.com/check.php?url=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

check.php

```
header("location: http://" . $_GET['url']);
```

But it`s looping.

Any ideas?

Comment: How does it know if it is coming from test.com? You never put in a way for it to tell the difference.

Comment: i can`t, it`s for checking cookies from main domain, user should not notice anything

Comment: I don't think mod_rewrite is what you are looking for. You'd need to redirect to main.com, then redirect back to test.com from there. Or just have the user stay at test.com and have this process going on in the background, either with php or ajax or both. I could do with a bit more info on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: user logged on main.com domain and if he going to another my domains (many of them), i need to checks from main domain if exists any cookies and redirect back, i have no ideas how to do this another way. It`s situation like on tumblr.com, when users have personal domains.

Answer (score 1):

**Best Option** I think what you're looking for is: Using a common domain to share sessions across multiple domains.  If so, check out this SO thread: [Sharing sessions across domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956214/cross-domains-sessions-shared-shopping-cart-cross-domains)

**OK Option** If you don't like that, you may be able to treat all your users' pages as separate services and implement a [Single sign on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) system.

**Stubborn Option** If that's not what you're looking for and you want to stick with mod_rewrite, all i could suggest is trying more `RewriteCond`s to disqualify the loop.  For instance, try adding: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !*some string* [NC, OR]` to the top of @nerkn's suggestion (and of course sending a query string in your check.php.

Comment: i saw it, but can`t understand how to get session id from third domain, it`s really my head pain all week

Comment: @swamprunner7, the session ID question belongs in its own thread (otherwise said, I don't know off the top of my head) :)  Good luck though!

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess does not  know script has checked, so I added referrer. But it is loose check, I think you should believe other mechanism. Referrer belief is dangerous, if there is danger.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !main\.com [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^main\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://main.com/check.php?url=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```