# symfony 1.4 session without using cookies

Tags: session, symfony1, single-sign-on, sfguard, cookieless

I have a Symfony application which use a mysql database to store session data, and uses the SfGuard plugin to manage the authentication.
 Despite that symfony allways save the authentication info in a cookie. Is there anyway i can disable cookies and store the authentication info in the database or in memory?
I might need in the future, to have a kind of single sign on feature, where the authentication state will persist between multiple applications, in different domains. Thats why I mostly want to eliminate the need to use cookies.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See here how to get sessions without cookies : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies is this what you really want? I guess the multi domain is not a problem: look at stack exchange, they have multiple sites, but there still is some synchronisation between sessions.

Comment: If I read that article well, for that to work i need to append the a session ID in the url. I dont want to do that. I want to store the authentication info in my database or in memory ($_SESSION['authenticated'] = true for example. If i disable cookies i cant login anymore in my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not seem to understand how sessions work.

That cookie that gets sent to the cient is called the session id, and it's unique to the visitor. When he reqests a page from the server that cookie identifies the row in your session table where his data are - no data besides the ID is ever sent to the client.

Without that ID there's no way to pair a request to session data, that's why you could not log in anymore after disabling the cookies. The alternative to the cookie is to pass the session id some other way, like in the url - php can do that automatically, you just need to enable `use_trans_sid` in the php.ini.

Comment: Yes, i have discovered that myself. I will accept your response as an answer. I will look for other solutions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956214/cross-domains-sessions-shared-shopping-cart-cross-domains

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store the authentication info in the database : See [here](http://www.lampjunkie.com/2008/05/store-symfony-sessions-in-database-with-doctrine/) how.

Comment: i already have database stored sessions in my app but it still uses cookies in authentication

Comment: Indeed. But I thought you would be glad to have part of what could be the solution.